# Keep executing a method while a button is pressed in android

Tags: android, button

I'm making a simple game in android, with a sprite in the middle controlled by 4 buttons,i want the method assigned to the button to move the sprite in the respective direction while it's pressed, i've tried to do this in onCreate method:

```
//initialization stuff...                               
button1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener{
@Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
    if(event.getAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        move_sprite();//for example
    return true;      
}});
```

But this only works one time when I press the button. I want the method to be executed while the button is pressed and also how to control the update time of the method.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean fingerDown = false;

button1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
        if(event.getAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
             fingerDown = true;
             move_sprite();
        } else if ( event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ){
             fingerDown = false;
        } 
        return true;      
    }
});

public void move_sprite(){
    // in new thread, or handler,
       while(fingerDown){
          // do your thing
       }
}
```

Comment: in the new thread?, how?, i don't understand, i know what a thread is, but i don't know how to implement it in another thread.

Comment: well, thats completely out of this questions scope. On top of that, if you don't know how to spin a thread and you are doing Android work, i would suggest you to read about to to stay away from the ui thread. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html